# Submit Date After 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in which there are two columns Date Status

```
Create table Status
(
    date nvarchar(20),
    Status bit
)
```

Now I want to select records whose status = false and date after 7 days of submit, like if today I have insert two records with false status so I want the query to show the record after 7 day on 8-04-2015 all the records of 1-04-2015 with status false should be show.

If you understand my question; please tell what to do.

Comment: You **need** to store dates as dates, not as strings.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gvee stated in the comment above, you should store dates as either `DATE` or `DATETIME` field.  This will allow you to query like so:

```
SELECT [date], [status]
FROM <yourtable>
WHERE [date] <= DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE())
AND [status] = 0
```

This will give you any results with a false status that are 7 days or older.

Alternatively, your `WHERE` clause could look like this:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, [date], GETDATE()) >= 7
AND [status] = 0
```

If you **absolutely must** keep your column as `NVARCHAR` data type, with the date format you provided, you can `CONVERT` it to a `DATETIME` like so:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, [date], 105)
```

So your `WHERE` clause would look like this:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, CONVERT(DATETIME, [date], 105), GETDATE()) >= 7
AND [status] = 0
```

Comment: how to cast ? my date is like this 1-04-2015

Comment: `CONVERT(DATETIME, [date], 105)`  I will add to the answer

Comment: Be sure to mark your question as answered if you have solved your issue.  I highly recommend using either `DATETIME` or `DATE` format, which will allow you much more flexibility when working with dates in the future.

Comment: Ok I will used date or datetime In future thanks again

Comment: I want to ask When put the data type in date format and then inserting the date in d-MM-yyyy format form my application but sql is showing me the format like this yyyy-mm-dd.I have change like this   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Request_Issue_date", sv.RequestIssue.ToString("d-MM-yyyy")); but its given me a error:Error converting data type nvarchar to date

Comment: Please post this as a new question, you will have a better chance of getting an answer that way.  Be sure to include the relevant code i.e. what you used before when it worked, and what you said here that gives you the error.  Also include some sample data as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. So much as it depends on you, you should store data using proper data types, like `DATE` or `DATETIME`.
2. You can use `DATEDIFF()` to find the difference between two dates in days/weeks/hours, etc.:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM YourTable
   WHERE [status] = 0
      AND DATEDIFF(day,YourDate,GETDATE()) >=7
   ```

If you absolutely cannot fix the data structure, you'll have to add a `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` around each usage of your string date:

```
CAST(YourDate AS DATETIME)
```